# 'computed property' may only be literal values in flow?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have a union type:

```
export type MyType = 
  'A'|
  'B'|
  'C';

const MyA = ('A': MyType)
const X = {[MyA]:true]
```

Flow complains about the last line, saying cannot use MyA as a computed property, computed properties must be primitive literal values. How do I properly initialize `X`

Comment: Using `const X = {[(MyA: string)]:true}` makes the error go away, but there could be a better way. I got my information from https://medium.com/flow-type/spreads-common-errors-fixes-9701012e9d58

Comment: bravo! excellent

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways of doing it.

One is using a literal to annotate the computed property

```
const X = {[(MyA: string)]:true}
```

Another one is to declare X first, and assign the key after.

```
const X: {[MyType]: boolean} = {}
X[MyA] = true
```